# minimal dominating set of a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-graph, set-theory

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set

Now, I got an idea to find it, and I need your opinion

First:
Create a rank system on the graph, every vertex has a rank.
rank of vertex is: 
 2*[the number of out-edges] - [the number of in-edges]

Second:
Alter the DFS algorithm: make it also return the group of all the roots on the spanning forest(does not change complexity)

The algorithm:
1. start with all the vertexes as minimal dominating set
2. run DFS with starting vertex: the highest ranked vertex
3. look at the root on the spanning forest, take the list of the minimal dominating set and delete every vertex who is not a root on the spanning forest
4. repeat 2-3 with the next highest ranked vertex who was remained on the minimal dominating set
5. stop when you ran a DFS on every vertex on the minimal dominating set
6. return it

I use adj-list, so DFS is O(|V| + |E|)
what do you think about this algorithm? will it work? can I do better? what is the amortized worst case of this algorithm?

Comment: In a directed graph does adjacency imply a directed edge from a non dominating vertex to a dominating vertex?

Comment: no, dominating set is group of vertexes that:<br/>for every vertex v at least one condition is true:<br/>1. v is in dominating set<br/>2. the is a directed path from one of the dominating vertexes to v

Comment: what? I didn't given a proved algorithm, its just an idea, and I wanted to hear what peoples think about it, lol don't use it yet :)

Comment: Finding minimal dominating set is NP-complete problem.

Comment: meaning this wont work?(dont know yet all this subject of complexities groups)

Comment: hmmmm, I dont see it...

Comment: @Sasha Finding the global minimum set is NP-complete. Minimal is only a local minimum.

Comment: @kittsil what is the difference?

Comment: @Sasha In this context, it means that removing any node from the set will make it no longer dominating. For instance, consider the linear graph `1-2-3-4-5`; the set `{1,3,5}` is a minimal dominating set (if you remove any of these, the set is no longer dominating). However, it is not a minimum dominating set, since you can construct dominating sets of size 2 (for instance, `{2,5}`). See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44774/difference-between-maximal-element-and-greatest-element

Answer (score 1):

**Will it work?**

No. A simple counter example is this graph:

[image: simple graph]

The ranks are `[1:6, 2:-1, 3:1, 4:-1, 5:-1].` On step 2, you run a DFS from vertex `1.` It is the only root in the spanning forest, so in step 3 you remove every other vertex and return. However, this is not a dominating set! `5` is neither in nor adjacent to a node in the dominating set.

**What is the amortized worst case of this algorithm?**

The worst case is O(|V|+|E|+k<sup>2</sup>), where k is the size of the returned set. You will remove everything but the roots on the first time through, so the next O(k) times through the loop will only take O(k) time each.

**Can I do better?**

Yes, in both correctness and speed. Remove all neighbors of the current vertex, and then move on to the next vertex still in the set. This will only take O(|V|+|E|).

It seems that you were attempting to get something that more closely approximates the global minimum; for this, I recommend checking the literature for "Minimum Dominating Set Approximation."

Comment: I wanted to find distance dominating minimal set, note that is: DISTANCE domination, 1 is indeed distance dominating the graph :)

Comment: @user4857930 You did not say that in your question. I do see that you mentioned "distance dominating set" in one comment, but again did not say that that was what you were looking for. If you would like to revise your question, I will revise my answer. But this is the answer to your question as it currently stands.

Comment: how do I "revise", simply edit the original post? BTW, sorry for the trouble and inconviniece :)